# Kubernetes cluster in public and private topology

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

I am trying to setup a kubernetes cluster in aws using Kops. But i have requirement like deploy the master nodes in public subnet and some workers in public and some workers in private subnet.

I need the network something like below:
[image]

So, is it possible to create this network using kops?

Comment: what scenario are you trying to implement?

Comment: @Ohmen I have frontend applications that should be available over public and applications that should run as jobs in private subnets.

Comment: Thank you for asking this! So hard to find an answer for this on the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kubernetes nodes should never be directly connected to the internet.

I assume you want to expose services via NodePort which is in general a bad idea. Because NodePort service are exposed on **ALL** nodes not just the ones where the pods are running.

You should place all nodes and masters in private Subnets and manage the external Access via elastic load balancers and [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/). This way you can explicitly expose frontend services to the internet.

The relevant `kops-spec.yaml` snippet would be:

```
topology:
  dns:
    type: Public
  masters: private
  nodes: private
```

Comment: you are welcome. Please accept the anwer if it solved your problem

Comment: I know this is little old, I have one question though (being a novice). As all k8s nodes should be in private subnet, how ingress will be accessible via internet? I am under the impression that ingress would also be installed on one of k8s node, then how would it be accessible via outside? or you mean to say that configure an ELB which connects to ingress (running on private subnet)

Comment: yes you would configure the ingress service of type `LoadBalancer`. This would trigger the creation of an ELB pointing at NodePorts forwarding to your ingress pod(s)